# Specify desktop as output

Tags: windows, file

I want to specify the Desktop as an output for the logfile, but since everyones username is different, how do I make it so it will work with any system?

Example:

```
"C:\Users\username\Deskop"
```

Every username is different so what do I need to put so it works on any computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to Bali C's answer this may be better should your users' profiles not be in the default location/drive:

```
%userprofile%\Desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `%username%` which will get you the username of whoever is currently logged onto the computer.

```
"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop"
```